# Removing first slash character from string PHP

Tags: php, string, performance, trim

I have a string of this format `/abcd-efg-sms-3-topper-2`

I want to remove the first `/` character from this.

I know I can remove this using `substr()` function, but I do not want to use that, since I first have to check if first character is the slash.  Is there any other way I can remove the slash, without first checking for the slash, and have that way be reasonably performant (i.e. avoiding complex regular expresions)?

Comment: Yes, reading the question trigger the ask about it: Which kind of faster are you concerned about? And also: Why faster? And do you really think you have got a speed issue with that 20-or-so character string?

Comment: yes because i am having large database and my page is taking time to load all things, that's why i want these function's faster response.

Comment: what has a large database to with that line of code? Have you actually metriced what takes so long with your website? The way you write this sounds a bit like, that you actually have no clue and you're "optimizing" on the wrong end, which, well, is just the opposite of what you try to achieve. Take a look what actually takes long, then you can ask for speed *about that part*.

Comment: Apart from that, `substr` is faster and you've accepted the wrong answer. But as written, you do not even notice that because you only ask but you do not care about speed. You give the best examples your own.

Comment: There are numerous ways to do this. Why are you looking for another way? And what are you looking for exactly? Have you tested the performance? Why do you hate `substr()`? This question cannot be answered with a single "The answer" so I am close voting it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use trim:

```
$string = '/abcd-efg-sms-3-topper-2';
echo ltrim($string, '/');
// abcd-efg-sms-3-topper-2
echo rtrim($string, '/');
// /abcd-efg-sms-3-topper-2
echo trim($string, '/');
// abcd-efg-sms-3-topper-2
```

Comment: Well, `substr` faster it just cut a string. `trim` checkout charlist for remove it from string;

Comment: But `trim` is safest in using than `substr`

Comment: well, if string do not have `/` your `substr` will remove first char any way. `trim` checking charlist, and remove this chars from string on border(left, right or both), and if string do not have searching string, string not be modified.

Comment: which is faster depends on the length of the string (and is normally totally irrelevant - as so often).

Comment: `trim` will remove multiple slashes too, so `trim('//foo/bar')` becomes 'foo/bar' which might not be what you want.